# How can I access model.input attribute after training of tensoflow keras model subclassing?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I defined a tensorflow model using model subclassing and fed the input image tensor through a for loop in the call method. But I am not able to access the model.input attribute after the model is built. A sample of the model is shown below:

```
class MNISTClassifier(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MNISTClassifier, self).__init__()
        
        # Define the layers
        #for feature extration
        self.conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28, 1))
        self.max_pool1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))
        self.conv2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu')
        self.max_pool2 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))
        self.flatten = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()
        self.dropout1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25)
        self.dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')
        self.dropout2 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)
        self.dense2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
        self.layers_list = [self.conv1, self.max_pool1, self.conv2, self.max_pool2,
                           self.flatten, self.dropout1, self.dense1, self.dropout2, self.dense2]
    @tf.function
    def call(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Define the forward pass
        # output is the model logits
        activation_list = []
        out = args[0]
        for layer in self.layers_list:                  
           out = layer(out)
           activation_list.append(out)

        
        return out
```

Here is the what the erro looks like;

```
   2077         """
   2078         if not self._inbound_nodes:
-> 2079             raise AttributeError(
   2080                 "Layer " + self.name + " is not connected, no input to return."
   2081             )

AttributeError: Layer mnist_classifier_2 is not connected, no input to return.
```